# Fastest 'update' on jdbc with PreparedStatement and executeBatch

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I have a java program that in some circumstances must update a large amount of records in a database (e.g 100,000).

The way it does it is by creating a `PreparedStatement` and by using the `addBatch` technique.
Here is the snippet:

```
connection.setAutoCommit(false);
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(
        "UPDATE myTable SET colName=? where id=?");

for (...) { // this loop can be 100000 long 
     colValue = ...
     id = ...
     ps.setString(1,colValue);
     ps.setString(2,id);
     ps.addBatch();
  }

ps.executeBatch();
connection.commit();
```

is this the best (fastest) way to update 100000 of records in JDBC ?

Could anybody suggest a better way ?

Comment: If there are bulk-type loads (inserts) you could insert the data into a temp table (only-memory?) and try some kind of joined update. I don't know much about MSSql but I know that there nice things to do bulk processing.

Answer (score 2):

Try this as a benchmark:

1. Use the built-in SQL tools to do a bulk extract of the entire table.  All rows.  All columns.
2. Drop (or rename) the table.
3. Use a simple flat-file read/write to create a new file with the updates applied.
4. Use the bulk-load utility that comes with your database to rebuild the entire table from the extracted file.
5. Add indexes after the reload.

You may find that this is faster than any SQL solution.  We stopped using UPDATES for a data warehouse because extract -> flat file process -> load was much faster than SQL.

Comment: It may be a rubbish answer but there are nicer ways of saying that.

Comment: @dan:     you are right, Dan. I was too rude.
@s.lott:  thanks for your unhelpful answer. I wonder how you manage to get so many points in StackOverflow. Surely the guys at StackOverflow should consider reworking their algorithms

Comment: Clearly S.Lott thinks you can get closer to an answer if you do a benchmark. Maybe you asked because you didn't know how to do it, because you hadn't time neither to learn enough about your DB. If there's a definitive answer someone will write it. If there's not, you'll have one not-so-helpful answer. And know what? I'm voting it because it encourage self-learning and understanding beyond a simple, questionable answer. We are programmers. We make things work.

Comment: @zerohibernation:  (1) It worked for me.  (2) It may not work for you.  (3) I'm not sure how much more detail you need.  Code?  (4) If you don't "benchmark", all you're doing is taking my word for it.  (5) You can ignore my answer politely.

Comment: @s.lott: I take it back. His answer is not too bad. Sincere apologies.
@helios: you say:
I'm voting it because it encourage self-learning and understanding beyond a simple, questionable answer.
so if somebody replies: 'go and find it out yourself' you could vote them again.

Comment: @zerohibernation: I don't think I said go and find out for yourself.  I think I suggested benchmarking the algorithm I described.  I'm not sure, but there seems to be a difference.  Perhaps my answer was unclear?

Comment: +1 for measuring, whether drop and rebuild of indexes increases performance depends on the number of rows already in the table and if they have to be preserved

Answer (score 0):

Since batching uses buffering on client side and then sends everything as a single request, it might be wise to execute batches with 5000 rows. You should watch you memory consumption when adding 100.000 rows.

Sometime it works faster to push data in several loads instead of 1 single load(using JDBC, at least based on my previous experience).

Answer (score 0):

dont use for loop use spring jdbc templete

```
public void Update(final List<Aclass> aclasss) {
 String sql = "UPDATE myTable SET colName=? where id=?";
GenericDAO.getJdbcTemplate().batchUpdate(sql, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {

    @Override
    public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
    Aclass aclass= aclasss.get(i);
                ps.setString(1,colValue);
                ps.setString(2,id);
            }

            @Override
            public int getBatchSize() {
                return aclasss.size();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use Spring Batch operations with the JdbcTemplate

Comment: But he doesn't want to use Spring

Comment: But maybe he should, Spring is all the rage these days